# Georeferencing Mosaic in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing, mosaic

I have a problem in my thesis, i georeference a lot of photos and after that i create a mosaic. But now, i know the ortho is shifting 5 meters.

Is possible to shift the mosaic without creating everithing again? a kind of georeferencing of a mosaic?

The Software is ArcGIS 10.3.

Comment: How are you so sure that the image shifted 5 meters? Maybe you are using a different projection and a reproject would solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

An mosaic can be georeferenced. Th method is described  [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/georeferencing-a-mosaic-dataset-item.htm). If your are sure that your raster is shifted 5 meters in one direction you could move it exactly 5 meters in the opposite direction.

Perhaps you have a backup of the proper georeferenced mosaic to just load and compare with the shifted one.